# Seg fault adding a node to linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, undefined-behavior, singly-linked-list, function-definition

In leetcode Add-Two-nums I am trying to loop over the two linked lists, in the first example I create a middle pointer to the allocated node and then add it to the original node, in the second example I try to get rid of this `ptr` variable and add the node directly but keep on getting a stack buffer overflow in leetcode for both examples and only a seg fault in the second example when compiling on my own machine the first example works fine

```
ListNode * addTwoNums(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2)
{
    ListNode *result;
    ListNode *tmp = result;
    int carry =0;
    int sum =0;

    while ( l1->next != NULL && l2->next != NULL)
    {
        sum = l1->val+l2->val+carry ; 
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", l1->val, l2->val, l1->val+l2->val);
        if ( sum > 9)
        {
            result->val = 0;
            carry = 1;
        } 
        else
        {
            result->val = sum;
            carry = 0;
        }
        ListNode *ptr = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); 
        result->next = ptr;
        l1 = l1->next;
        l2 = l2->next;
        result = result->next;
    } 
}
```

In this example I remove the pointer `ptr` and try to add the allocated Node directly to the next value but I get a seg fault

```
ListNode * addTwoNums(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2)
{
    ListNode *result;
    ListNode *tmp = result;
    int carry =0;
    int sum =0;

    while ( l1->next != NULL && l2->next != NULL)
    {
        sum = l1->val+l2->val+carry ; 
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", l1->val, l2->val, l1->val+l2->val);
        if ( sum > 9)
        {
            result->val = 0;
            carry = 1;
        } 
        else
        {
            result->val = sum;
            carry = 0;
        }
        result->next = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); 
        l1 = l1->next;
        l2 = l2->next;
        result = result->next;
    } 
}
```

Comment: At least this makes no sense because `result` is uninitialized: `ListNode *result;
    ListNode *tmp = result;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this while loop

```
while ( l1->next != NULL && l2->next != NULL)
```

can already invoke undefined behavior if at least one of the passed lists is empty.

The pointer result is uninitialized

```
ListNode *result;
```

So at least this statement

```
result->val = 0;
```

also invokes undefined behavior.

And setting the data member `val` to `0` in any case does not make a sense.

Pay attention to that after the while loop one of the passed pointers can be a non-null pointer. You need also to process it after the while loop.

Comment: As stated in the leetcode problem neither l1 nor l2 can be empty, as for the `ListNode *result` can be set to `NULL` and `result->val =0;` here i am trying to set the number in the current node to zero since the sum of the two numbers and the carry is bigger than ten

Comment: @prometheus It is unimportant what is written in the leetcode. You are writing a general function. So it must not invoke undefined behavior. Also you may not use a null pointer to access memory. And if  the sum of two digits is greater than 10 then you need to stored the difference num1 + num2 - 10 in the cjurrent node.

Comment: isn't the difference always 1 ?

Comment: @prometheus Consider num1 = 5, num2 = 9, num1 + num2 - 10 = 4. so you need to allocate dynamically a new node for the result list and store 4 in it. Also the carry flag will be set to 1.

Comment: yeah but what if you had 4 and 6 in this situation you will not have a carry and `val` will be equal to zero

Comment: @prometheus You have carry equal to 1 and the value equal to 0.